# Technology to use synchronous requests client->server

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, signalr

I'm using thegamesdb.com 's API to get all gaming platforms and all games on each platform.
At the moment, I start with a blank page, on document.ready, I do an AJAX call to the server to get all the platforms. Then I have to do another AJAX call for each platform to get a count of games on that platform (ex. PC has 2342 games, XBOX has 453 games, ...).
The reason I'm doing this call too, is to provide the user a progress bar (0-100%) and to show the number of the game on the total games of the platform:
/

So after these API calls, I should have a list of all the platforms which can be clicked to start another serverside call to do an api call for each game, to get the data of it. When a platform is clicked, the client sends a new call each time so that the server puts the game data in the database. Then we do the gamecounter++.

I've tried doing this with AJAX calls to the server:

```
$.getJSON($('#platformlist').data('url-getplatforms'), function (data) {
    self.platforms = $.map(data, function(p) { return new Platform(p); });
    console.log(self.platforms);
    $.each(self.platforms, function () {
        console.log(this);
        $.getJSON($('#platformlist').data('url-getplatformgames'), { platformId: this.id }, function (platformgamesdata) {
            this.countGamesDone = 0;
            $.each(platformgamesdata, function() {
                this.games.push(new PlatformGame(this));
                this.countGames++;
            });

        });
    });
});
```

But since this is async, this can not show the progress and just makes the browser load until all the games are in the database without any feedback.
I could put the AJAX on async:false, but I've read that there are other ways of doing this, but no one says how to do it.

What are other options of doing this? I have no restrictions on what technologies to use. It's an ASP.NET MVC 5 application. I can use javascript, c#, signalr, jquery and any other javascript library if this can simplify this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why can't you display a floating `loading` message?

```
$('#bigFatLoadingMessage').show();

$.getJSON($('#platformlist').data('url-getplatforms'), function (data) {
    self.platforms = $.map(data, function(p) { return new Platform(p); });
    $.each(self.platforms, function () {

        //update overlay message
        $('#bigFatLoadingMessage').html('Loading platform ' + this.name);

        $.getJSON($('#platformlist').data('url-getplatformgames'), { platformId: this.id }, function (platformgamesdata) {
            this.countGamesDone = 0;
            $.each(platformgamesdata, function() {
                this.games.push(new PlatformGame(this));
                this.countGames++;
            });

        });
    });

    $('#bigFatLoadingMessage').hide();
});
```

Comment: As said in the question, I'm trying to show a progress, because it's over 16k API calls, so just a gif turning around for around 10 minutes isn't alot of feedback to the user how much calls are still to come

Comment: so why can`t you update the text in the overlay? You got the ID to it and know when you load something else

Comment: Because the way I'm doing it now, is async, so, it starts 50-100 requests before giving feedback for the first and that goes on and on. Also, the calls don't get finished, because the next call is done before the first is finished, and it skips getting data for 99% of the calls. It should be made synchronous to make the 'show progress' system work. And I'm trying to find out what the best way to do the synchronous calls is.